# Create Exe of C# forms with Database connection

Tags: c#

how to add sql server details in c# application connection string, i have installed sql on local machine and its working fine with following connection string

```
connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=container_inspection_report;Integrated Security=True"`
```

now i want to connect it with sql installed on some local server, but unable to find the solution that how can i add connection string of server, as i am new to c#

Comment: Is your connection string referring the SQL instance by local name? From the second machine, can you connect to the SQL DB using SSMS?

Comment: yes let me share the connection string with you..
connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=container_inspection_report;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: Have you set up the SQL Server installation on your shared server?

Comment: so you mean i need to install ssms on second machine and connect ssms with my server on which sql is installed ?

Comment: yes i installed sql on my shared server

Comment: ssms is not sql server. It's just one tool you can use to connect to and manage Sql Server.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your connection string. You are pointing to the local instance. The application on any machine will try to connect to the DB on that machine. Update the connection string to point to the machine name or IP address.

Comment: Thanks .. ok can you please share some kind of tutorial link with me regarding my issue so i can learn and follow the steps.

Comment: Everything you ever wanted to know about connection strings:  https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: @willman Great connection string link reference!...

Comment: @willman thanks, let me try will let you know..

Answer (score 0):

Couple of possibilities:

1. Since you developed on your machine, which is also where the sql server is located, your database connection string may be pointing to "(local)" or "localhost", which would not work when executed on a machine without sql installed.  Check your connection string (most likely in your app.config) to make sure it is referencing your machine by DNS name that can be resolved by other computers.
2. If you are hosting SQL server on your desktop computer, it is likely that either the windows built-in firewall, or whatever anti-malware you are running, could be blocking access from other machines.  [Check to make sure the right ports are open](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Docs-v1.1.2/GUID-CF5C89EA-0918-4002-8391-80CBEDE0BB5E).

Comment: yes sql string is pointing to my local machine, can you please share, how can i add sql connection string, of server sql database

Comment: See my comment on the other answer about using connectionstrings.com to help you figure out your server reference. If this answer helped, please be sure to [mark it as such](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)